# problem with \left. \right| around an array

Tags: arrays, delimiters

I am trying to typeset synthetic division. I am using the following code:

```
\[
\left.\begin{array}[t]{c}1\\ \,\end{array}\right|\!\begin{array}[t]{cccc}1& 2& -5& 2\\ & 1& 3& -2\\ \hline 1& 3& -2& 0\end{array}
\]
```

The output I get is the following:

[image]

Why does the vertical line go way beyond the top of the array?

I need a vertical line of the size of the first two lines of the array on the right.
I am trying to achieve it using KaTeX so I can only use the commands KaTeX supports. Adding extra packages is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply use this code?

```
\[
\begin{array}[t]{c|}1\\ \,\end{array}\enspace \begin{array}[t]{rrrr}1& 2& -5& 2\\ & 1& 3& -2\\ \hline 1& 3& -2& 0\end{array}
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed, I have not thought about it, but it works perfectly. Thank you! Nevertheless, I would still be curious why is my code giving longer delimiter. It seems, that the top alignment confuses \left \right.

Comment: Probably it is because the (unique) row  – or the array – has some invisible spacing at the top.

Comment: I tried adding text around this line, it did not make a difference.I also changed it to inline math, it did not make a difference either. I do not think there is some invisible space in the array, I think it would also make the vertical line in your edit go up.I was thinking about it a bit more and I rather think that the \left ... \right height is calculated symmetric to the alignment position, which in this case produces a strange looking result.

Comment: I think you have the correct explanation.

Comment: @FerencBeleznay yes which is the issue the delarray package addresses, it shifts the delimiter alongside the array as you use `[t]` or `[b]`